# FusionTablesLayer where clause not filtering data

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have been looking at a lot of examples recently on how to use the FusionTablesLayer to display an area on a Google Map. I have put together a fusion table and have created a view for it. This can be found here ([View of Data](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1NpDIypHO58j9k1BAOr1tniCgoOPUkdbKBsXgTVCS)).

However, the following snippet of code does not seem to filter the data based on the where clause.

```
var provinces = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
   map: $scope.map,
   query: {
     select: "*",
     from: "1NpDIypHO58j9k1BAOr1tniCgoOPUkdbKBsXgTVCS",
     where: "'PROVINCE' = '02'",
     limit: 100
   },
   suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

This actually still fetches and shows all the four provinces and seems to disregard the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use "*" for the select, that should be the column containing the geographic information (in your case `geometry`).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kwzrxk5b/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.669177995538305, -7.1375505556775405),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
      enabled: false
    },
    query: {
      select: "geometry",
      from: "1NpDIypHO58j9k1BAOr1tniCgoOPUkdbKBsXgTVCS",
      where: "PROVINCE = '02'"
    },
    options: {
      styleId: 2,
      templateId: 2
    }
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="mapDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Absolutely right. That's what I was missing. Thank you so much.